# Bar bell position when coming down during deadlift

Tags: deadlifts

Simple question. I'm aware that the bar bell has to touch the shins and thighs as it's coming up BUT as it's coming down should it or should you force it to touch your shins?

I find that as the bar bell comes down it doesn't touch my shins and is about an inch or two away from them.

Comment: You're probably not maintaining enough tension in your upper back.

Answer (score 1):

Right, the reason it travels touching the shins is because the resistance is close to your center of gravity.  Drift like that means the bar is moving away from the center of gravity, which could mean more lower back activation.  All in all, the bar should technically travel in a straight line, up and down.